# How to find the zeros of a Complex trigonometric function

Tags: plotting

I tried this

```
ContourPlot[(-100 - 
     50 Cos[γ]) Sin[β] (50 Cos[γ] Sin[β] - (
     50 Cos[β] Cos[γ] (-200 + 
        Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ])))/Sqrt[
     6400 - (200 - Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ]))^2]) + 
  50 Cos[β] Sin[γ] (Cos[β] (50 + 
        50 Sin[γ]) + (
     Sin[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ]) (-200 + 
        Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ])))/Sqrt[
     6400 - (200 - 
        Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ]))^2]), {β, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {γ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

but it does not produce anything.

Could someone explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: Your function returns Complex results almost everywhere. Contour plotting needs real valued functions

Comment: Many thanks, the function is the determinant of a matrix, I want ot know where the function equals to zero, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can format your code better by putting four spaces at the front of every code block (or click on the curly-brace button above the question editing area). Further, wrap short inline code snippets in a pair of backticks ``. This will make your post easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Your determinant will be zero when the Real and Imaginary parts are zero.
We can plot the contours independently for both and your answer is the intersection:

```
f[β_, γ_] := (-100 - 50 Cos[γ]) Sin[β] (50 Cos[γ] Sin[β] - (50 Cos[β] Cos[γ] (-200 + 
               Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ])))/ Sqrt[6400 - (200 - Cos[β] (50 + 50 
               Sin[γ]))^2]) + 50 Cos[β] Sin[γ] (Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ]) + (Sin[β] (50 + 
               50 Sin[γ]) (-200 + Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ])))/ Sqrt[6400 - (200 - 
               Cos[β] (50 + 50 Sin[γ]))^2])

ContourPlot[{Re@f[β, γ], Im@f[β, γ]}, {β, 0, 2 Pi}, {γ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Contours -> {{0}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Thickness[.01], 
                 Line[{{0, 3/2 Pi}, {2 Pi, 3/2 Pi}}], 
                 Point[Pi {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {3/2, 1/2}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Seems to be missing solutions, e.g., beta=Pi, gamma=2Pi.

Comment: But I don't know what do "Point[Pi {{1, 1}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2}, {3/2, 1/2}, 
                                {1, 3/2}, {1/2, 3/2}, {3/2, 3/2}}]" means, could you explain it please.

Comment: @weiye I'm drawing red points by hand at the intersections

Comment: @weiye And the red line too

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Comment: @belisarius Why does the red line should be drawn? Seems that it is not the intersection line

Comment: @weiye `f[x, 3/2 Pi] == 0` for all x

Comment: Sorry, I look more closely and find that is is the intersection line. Thank you.